# Find total of grid view

Tags: gridview, grid, cell

How to find a total in grid view cell value. Consider in grid view there are 3 rows are there named as row1 , row2 , and row3. Here I want to find a total of row1 contains 7 columns named as m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7 find the total of these columns and display in to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you can did this calculation listing for the RowDataBound event of the MS GridView, however more straight-forward means I use during my development is to take advantage of the [calculated column](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/calculatedcolumns/defaultcs.aspx) of the Telerik web grid.

Hope these pointers help.

Dick